# Itinerary in the elements

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I need to extract the information from the vehicles so many times they appear in the searches, now with this code I always go through it, and I need to be able to go to the next one

The url is: [link](https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear=2019&doFiltering=true&exSuppliers=&fromLocChoose=true&filterTo=49&dropLocationName=Salta&ftsType=C&ftsLocationSearch=161&dropFtsSearch=L&doDay=28&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth=5&dropFtsInput=Salta&prefcurrency=USD&dropCountry=Argentina&puDay=25&dropFtsLocationSearch=161&puHour=10&dropFtsEntry=22776&enabler=&distance=10&reducedCategory=medium&ftsEntry=22776&city=Salta&ordering=price&driverage=on&filterName=CarCategorisationSupplierFilter&dropCity=Salta&dropFtsType=C&ftsAutocomplete=Salta%20Argentina&driversAge=30&dropFtsAutocomplete=Salta%20Argentina&dropFtsLocationName=Salta&dropCountryCode=&doMinute=0&countryCode=&advSearch=&filterAdditionalInfo=&puYear=2019&locationName=&puMinute=0&ftsInput=Salta&coordinates=-24.7833%2C-65.4167&dropLocation=161&doHour=10&dropCoordinates=-24.7833%2C-65.4167&ftsLocationName=Salta&ftsSearch=L&location=161&doMonth=5&filterCoordinates=-24.7909%2C-65.4089%3A-24.79123%2C-65.40833%3A-24.7931%2C-65.41%3A-24.79%2C-65.408%3A-24.79103974%2C-65.40971696)

```
numberCars = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'carResultRow_CarDetails')]"))
for i in range(numberCars):

    Page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    Currency = Page.find('span', {'class': 'carResultRow_Price-now'})
    Date = Page.find('span', 'carResultRow_Price-duration')
    vehicle_model = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td.carResultRow_CarSpec>h2")

    for each_div in Page.findAll('div','search-summary__date'):
        print(each_div)
```

Comment: you're using selenium? why are you iterating over `range(numberCars)`?

Comment: @xxbinxx If I use selenium and bs4, I'm iterating to know how many vehicles are in that search and be able to extract the data of each one

Comment: what exact data are you looking for? I'll give you some idea and then you can work it out yourself.

Comment: Those that are in the marked image, the name of the vehicle, the price and the description, so with each one that appears in the search and many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the idea for you, I'm sure you will understand what you're doing wrong.

You are iterating over wrong thing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = '<your url>'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

rows = soup.select('.carResultRow_CarDetails') # select all car rows in the page
for row in rows:
    # Get price, you can get more details in similar manner.
    Price = row.find('span', {'class': 'carResultRow_Price-now'}) 
    print(Price.text)
```

**Output:**

```
US$141.21
US$150.92
US$173.79
US$191.07
US$228.67
US$248.61
US$251.53
US$283.55
```

Comment: Hi, this answer is not working, 
rows = soup.select ('. carResultRow_CarDetails') always gives me zero

Comment: Check again, must be something that you're doing wrong, do you want me to send a snapshot? Do you have a suggestion?